# Integrate React component with Angular

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, minify, web-frameworks

I found a rather large graphing framework for React (15.0.0). But I use Angular (4.4.0-RC). How do I proceed?

Do I rewrite my whole project in React? - Can I pass data acquired through Angular's HttpClient to React components? - Is there a trick to minifying it all together, e.g.: through .angular-cli.json or vanilla webpack?

Comment: A former colleague of mine had a talk about how his company moved from Angular to React gradually (not a total rewrite, but having them side by side a long time). It has some code examples and mentions about libraries that were used (if I remember correctly). https://opbeat.com/community/posts/from-angular-to-react-and-mobx-by-marcus-lonnberg/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I assume he's using similar versions of React and Angular? - I do rather like Angular, it's just that its ecosystem needs a little more work. I'm getting into @angular/material; but there is simply no good charting framework for Angular.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed the part about the version. At the time we were using using the old 1.x  Angular. So maybe there's not much in that talk that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I rewrite my whole project in React?

I would look for a vanilla JS library that does the same.

> Can I pass data acquired through Angular's HttpClient to React components?

You can integrate angular 2 and react quite easily as react only works on a particular dom node.

You can use a data managment library like `mobx` that allows sharing between angular and react.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's right. Looks like they're just a very neat abstraction layer atop d3; so I could just use pure d3 (with the code in my `foo.component.ts`; with one `d3.select` to its `foo.component.html`)